# Searching through redis keys python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

So I have around 1,250+ keys I am trying to search through, the reason is to check if the current time of a key is the current time and preform a task but I keep getting errors from redis

```
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/c/Desktop/DailyQuotes/main.py", line 415, in <module>
    bot.run('c')
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 705, in run
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 176, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/c/Desktop/DailyQuotes/main.py", line 316, in check_times
    entry = redis_client.get(key)
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1600, in get
    return self.execute_command("GET", name)
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1218, in execute_command
    return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 45, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1219, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1195, in _send_command_parse_response
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1234, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 821, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 320, in read_response
    raw = self._buffer.readline()
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 251, in readline
    self._read_from_socket()
  File "/Users/c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 194, in _read_from_socket
    data = self._sock.recv(socket_read_size)
```

Here is the code:

```
    current_time = datetime.now()
    now = current_time.strftime("%H:%M")
    for key in redis_client.scan_iter():
        entry = redis_client.get(key)
        data = json.loads(entry)['Time']
        if data == now:
            print(f"From task {key}:{now}")
            await daily_task(key)
            redis_client.delete(key)
        else:
            pass
```

And it is on a loop to constantly check. Not sure the best way to parse through all of the keys without timing out which I assume that is happening so any suggestions?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show FULL error message so we can't see all details and it hard to say what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated to the full error

Comment: at the beginning of error message it shows problem with line `bot.run('c')` which I don't see in your code. As for me problem is NOT redis but bot has problem to connect with server `discord`.

Comment: by the way: you didn't show FULL error message. You added beginning of error message (so I could see that problem is with `bot.run()`) but you didn't add end of error mesasge which show description of problem.

Comment: I thought that is all it showed but not sure, I think I fixed it by changing how frequently it ran the task because I think it kept timing out as it called to run again but didn't finish it the first time.